# Google Script behaving differently when in spreadsheet open trigger or assigned to button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is intended to keep track of expenses. Since more often than not, what I want is to append new expenses at the end of the table, I have created a script (mostly by importing an example found here in Stack Overflow) that jumps to the first blank line based on column A as follows:

```
function jumpToBlankLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var maxIndex = values.reduce(function(maxIndex, row, index) {
    return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
  }, 0);
  sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 1));
}
```

If anyone have comments or suggestions about the function above, they will be welcome! But my question is regarding it's behavior.

**Behavior 1:**
I have set a trigger upon spreadsheet opening that works perfectly: after loading the spreadsheet it jumps to the first blank line in column A and if I start typing right after (the expense date in my case), the cell starts to get filled by what I'm typing.

**Behavior 2:**
But, when I assign this same function to a button (a drawing) and I click it, the spreadsheet goes to the right cell, but it ignores what I type right after. To have the cell filled by what I'm typing, I must click on it.

The behavior I want is like **Behavior 1** above. I have also tried the function `Sheet.activate()` with no success.

Anybody have any ideas about why this is happening or a possible solution or workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because the drawing that you clicked on to run the script is actually the active object. You can confirm this by hitting return after you click on the drawing that runs the script.

Adding the below line of code to the `onOpen` function works as you expect but it still requires 2 clicks but less mouse travel than the drawing and doesn't require that you scroll to find it. (It creates a custom menu next to the help menu in sheets)

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Function').addItem('Go to last row','onOpen').addToUi();
```

Comment: Both your test suggestion to confirm if the actual active object was the drawing (hitting return) and solution (adding a custom menu) worked just as you said. Thanks for guiding me to the solution!